# Should I use headless mode in Spring-boot based backend?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm

I'm working on a application based on a simple monolithic architecture :rest API backend with spring-boot + frontend with a Js framework.

I have been reading about the headless mode when running java apps and I would like to know if running the embedded tomcat with my spring-boot application in headless mode is a good idea.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of headless and -D option in JAVA\_OPTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17501356/meaning-of-headless-and-d-option-in-java-opts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you don't need to specify `-Djava.awt.headless=true` because since around Java 1.8 the JRE determines itself whether a graphics environment is available or not and switches into headless mode if no graphics environment is available.

Relevant source in Java 11: https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11/blob/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/java/awt/GraphicsEnvironment.java#L166

- if you are running a Unix-like operating system and the `DISPLAY` environment variable is not set the `headless` is true
- on Windows it is assumed that a graphics device is always present and therefore `headless` is false

Answer (score 0):

In general, running an application in a console requires some sort of terminal to write to.

In Unix-based systems, these terminals are referred to as [tty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tty_(Unix)).

This implies the following:

Whenever you open a connection to your server via SSH, you get a tty. Your non-headless application will run in that tty until the tty is closed. To avoid that, you'd need something like [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen).

For Windows systems: If you close the cmd window of the console/sign off the user, the application server will also stop running.

That's why productive installations are usually headless and service based.

So much for the background, the [official docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html#deployment.installing) actually state the following:

> In addition to running Spring Boot applications by using java -jar, it
> is also possible to make fully executable applications for Unix
> systems. A fully executable jar can be executed like any other
> executable binary or it can be registered with init.d or systemd. This
> helps when installing and managing Spring Boot applications in common
> production environments.

This is described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html#deployment.installing.nix-services).